# storing allocated objects in stl list

Tags: c++, stl

I am currently working on a quadtree data structure.

I am taking an object oriented approach in C++. I have a class for the quad tree and my class has a pointer to a struct called node, which gets allocated with the new keyword.

That struct contains an an stl list  children. Every time I split my quadtree I populate my list with :

node *newnode = new node.

p_node->children.push_back(*newnode) //where p_node is the parent node

Thus since I used new I must free up the memory. 
The way I am doing this is I am transversing  down the tree and clearing the children from each stl list and then I delete the root. However valgrind is telling me I have memory leaks. I was wondering if someone could explain how to free data that is dynamically allocated and stored in an stl list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list must be storing objects, not pointers (as evident by the fact that you are deferencing `newnode` when calling `push_back()`):

```
list<node> p_node;
```

When you `push_back()` you are storing a *copy* of the source object, so you have to `delete` the original object you allocate with `new` or it will be leaked:

```
node *newnode = new node;
p_node.push_back(*newnode); // <-- makes a copy
delete node; // <-- must free original
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
node newnode;
p_node.push_back(newnode);
```

Or even:

```
p_node.push_back(node());
```

That being said, if you want to store pointers in your list, you have to do this instead:

```
list<node*> p_node;
...
node *newnode = new node;
p_node.push_back(newnode);
```

And then traverse `p_node` deleting objects when you are done using them:

```
for (list<node*>::iterator i = p_node.begin(); i != p_node.end(); ++i)
    delete *i;
p_node.clear();
```

If you are using C++11, you can use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead of naked pointers, as both are container-safe (unlike `std::auto_ptr`, which is not). Let the STL manage the memory for you, no traversing needed when you are done with the nodes:

```
list<unique_ptr<node>> p_node;
...
unique_ptr<node> newnode(new node);
p_node.push_back(newnode);
```

```
list<shared_ptr<node>> p_node;
...
auto newnode = make_shared<node>();
p_node.push_back(newnode);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This cleared up a lot of things for me.

Answer (score 0):

I see a series of problems here

1) Why do you want to 'new' a pointer instead of passing an object?
something like

```
Node n;
parent_node.push_back(n); // Copy or move constructor here
```

2) Why, why do you want naked pointers ?!? Don't do it! If you need pointer semantics use smart pointers and your ressources are managed.

```
auto n = make_shared<Node>();
parent_node.push_back(n);
```

BTW why or how do you have the node as pointer but the parent_node as value/reference?

Use this saturday to do some research, I recommend [GotW #89](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/) or if for any reason you can't use C++11 use boost [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)

Comment: sorry about this I wrote my description wrong. 

 My struct is called node. And in my struct I have a list called children. Thus I keeping a list of nodes that my struct connects downwards to.